# pyca/cryptography and "BestAvailableEncryption"

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography

I've been looking at the pyca cryptography documents on cryptography.io, but can't determine how the `BestAvailableEncryption` determines which encryption to use.

I recognize that it's using the underlying openssl implementation, so do I need to look at how openssl determines this? I'm not that clued up on openssl and it's inner workings.

Is there a documented flow for this? Is there a *python-esque* way to determine what encryption `BestAvailableEncryption` is being used?

Alternatively, is there a way to determine what encryption is in the `pkcs12_best_encryption` object?

This is my sample code:

```
pkcs12_best_encryption = serialization.pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates(
    name=b"My Certificate",
    key=private_key,
    cert=certificate,
    cas=None,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(passphrase)
)
```

Any guidance is most welcome.

TIA

Comment: You can probably only figure it out from the source code, e.g. [v40.0.2](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/40.0.2/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py#L2193), which may change (as can be seen by comparing older version). If you want it easier, *openssl pkcs12 -info...* or an ASN.1 parser are options. However, starting from v38 the algorithm can be set (s. 2nd code snippet to [`serialize_key_and_certificates()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I appreciate it. I'll take a look at the source code and figure it out from there.